# Maven recognize SSH key but it asks password again in Deploy

Tags: java, maven, ssh, deployment, settings

I'm working in project where I have to deploy a project in staging with Maven,
My SSH key is on the server because when I connect via SSH it works , but as soon as I want to deploy via IntelliJ with this command `mvn -DskipTests clean compile package install deploy`

It finds my ssh key in the settings.xml but it still asks me for the password.
I have tried several thins found on the internet but nothing works...

Here is my configuration for server in the settings.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings>
    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>example.repo</id>
            <username>user</username>
            <privateKey>C:/Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa</privateKey>
        
        </server>
```

Comment: This: `clean compile package install deploy` is wrong. Use `clean deploy` only.

Comment: Is your deployment to a repository or a installation?

Comment: This is a repository in .m2 folder, for found dependancy and after deploy in server.

Comment: clean deploy don't change anything, he ask me password...

Comment: So the deploy you are doing not a deploy of artifacts to a repository/repository manager. So you deploy to a server which will running your application?

Comment: Yes , it's a Jar with configuration File, and application is a Route Camel

Comment: Ok...how have you configured to use deploy phase to deploy to a server instead of a repository manager and why?